# Override Search Bar in UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, algolia

I have a `UISearchController` with a separate results controller.  I am using Algolia Instant Search to search for items.  However, I have an issue connecting the searchControllers' searchBar to the Algolia searchBarControllers' searchBar. inside the following method;

`func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)`

Essentially what I need to do is;

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.isActive {
        searchBarController.searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    }
}
```

this will not work due to;

> Cannot assign to property: 'searchBar' is a 'let' constant

Comment: Try making your searchBar as var in your function make var s = searchBarController.searchBar and then in your .isActive condition assign s. Hope that works

Comment: Can you elaborate please.

Comment: func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) { var s = searchBarController.searchBar if searchController.isActive {
       s  = searchController.searchBar
    }
}

Comment: It will write to the variable but doesn't read it.